# Ambiguity during Custom Sorting of TreeMap

Tags: java, oop, collections, frameworks

the ouptput for the below code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
    TreeMap<String, Integer> tm = new TreeMap<>((a, b) -> -a.length() + b.length());

    for (String k : s) {
        tm.merge(k, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    System.out.println(tm);
    }
```

the output should be:

```
{abc=1, def=1, ghi=1}
```

Comment: *"the ouptput for the below code is"*.... ?

Answer (score 1):

> ... the output should be {abc=1, def=1, ghi=1}

There is no reason to expect this behavior. Every comparison operation yields zero (i.e. "equal") for your sample data, and there's no guarantee in the specification (i.e. the Javadoc) that `TreeMap` preserves insertion order for equal keys.  If you want to preserve insertion order you'll need to use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: To be more precise, it’s guaranteed that a `Map` doesn’t store multiple equal keys at all. Since it only keeps the first encountered key, there’s no ordering relationship between equal keys.

Answer (score 0):

The output `{abc=3}` is not ambigous. You use the custom comparator, that treats all keys with **same length** as a same keys. And finally, the keys with greater length will be at the beginning.

***P.S.** `TreeMap` is the `Map` implementation where keys are unique and sorted with given `Comparator`.*

```java
String[] s = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "abc", "def", "abc" };
Map<String, Integer> tm = new TreeMap<>();

for (String k : s) {
    tm.merge(k, 1, Integer::sum);
}

System.out.println(tm);
```

**Output:**

```
{abc=3, def=2, ghi=1}
```